# Apache + Passenger + Rails deployment (File does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, passenger

So I'm deploying with capistrano to a apache + passenger setup; however I keep getting a passenger error:

```
PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner::Error
```

Everytime I try to hit the host. Checking the error logs for apache I'm getting this

```
File does not exist: /var/appvisit/current
```

My apache virtual host file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName appvisit
  DocumentRoot /var/appvisit/current/public
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/appvisit-access_log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/appvisit-error_log
  RailsBaseURI /
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /var/appvisit/current/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/appvisit/current/public>
```

Your DocumentRoot and Directory are different. Is this intentional?

Comment: Not intentional but fixing it and restarting apache still has same error

Comment: yep edited (with the help of aldo)... now reflects my new config

Comment: in terminal what does ls /var/appvisit/current return are you sure that its a directory? Sorry for the obvious question. I am wondering whats pointing to it as a file?

Comment: I am thinking the problem now exists somewhere in your ruby code not your server config.

Comment: cd'ing into that directory works just fine and has my rails app that was pushed there via capistrano. The rails app is working fine on my localhost though... I'll keep digging. Any particular parts of my code you think I should look?